# The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook error 123.) in Corona

Tags: facebook, share, coronasdk, fbconnect, showdialog

I am making a game for iOS using Corona SDK. I have integrated Facebook login and score share functionality in this. I have a problem that if I login my game through facebook's developer id and click fb button to share score, login works well and score share also works perfectly fine with showDialog() function.
But if I use any other Facebook account to login, login goes fine but score share crashes and gives me following error in crash log:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook error 123.) corona

Comment: Posting some code of your system would help a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your app is using features that require approval by Facebook to support (almost any posting feature needs approved)0.  Test accounts are allowed to work but general accounts will not work.  Facebook has seriouslly restricted what apps can do and now have submission process to allow doing just about anything.